# Freemarker : list of objects which contains other object

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to print a list of objects which contains other object with the  FreeMarker language

For example I have a Java object :

```
public class Adress
{
   private String _street;
   private String _city;
}
```

and another Java object :

```
public class House
{
     private int _nb_room;
     private Adress _adressHouse;
}
```

After I create a list with the data of my bdd  :

```
public Collection<House> getHousesList()
{
   Collection<House> housesList = new ArrayList<House>();
   DAOUtil daoUtil = new DAOUtil( "SELECT nb_room, street, city FROM house", bdd);
   while(daoUtil.next())
   {
      House tmpHouse = new House();
      tmpHouse.setNbRoom(daoUtil.getString(1));

      Adress tmpAdress = new Adress();
      tmpAdress.setStreet(daoUtil.getString(2));
      tmpAdress.setStreet(daoUtil.getString(3));

      tmpHouse.setAdress(tmpAdress);
      housesList.add(tmpAdress);
   }
   daoUtil.free();
}
```

In another file I send the list to the html :

```
model.put('houseList',model.put('housesList',getHousesList());
```

And in my html I have :

```
<table>
   <#list houseList houseTmp>
      <tr>
         <td>${houseTmp.nb_room!''}</td>
         <td>${houseTmp.adressHouse.street!''}</td>
         <td>${houseTmp.adressHouse.city!''}</td>
      </tr>
   </#list>
</table>
```

When I look at my HTML on my browser there is only the number of room who print but not the address but when I do a break point before send the list to the HTML there is address inside.

So how can I access to the address of the house?

Comment: Do you have `getAdressHouse()` or `getAdress()` in your `House` class?

Comment: Yes i have it but i don't write it : i have all the getter and setter

Comment: Have you tried `${houseTmp.adress.street!''}`?

Comment: you mean ${houseTmp.adressHouse.street!''} ... because it's what i do else just adress mean nothing no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `private Adress _adressHouse;` in your `House` class.

Freemarker will not look at that, but at the public getter you might have.

If you have `getAdressHouse()`, use `${houseTmp.adressHouse.street!''}`. If you have `getAdress()`, use `${houseTmp.adress.street!''}`.

I'm guessing it is the second case, as you declared `tmpHouse.setAdress(tmpAdress);`

Comment: Thanks  for this explain i didn't know that ... but it still not work

Comment: But your comment help me to understand my mistake. Thanks.